# Constructor from scanner (Java)

Tags: constructor

```
public Note( Scanner input )
{
    freq = input.nextInt();
}
```

The above code is in a separate file with everything it needs to run.

```
    public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e )
    {
    char key = e.getKeyChar();

    if( 'a' <= key && key <= 'y' )
    {
      // Ex5:  put code here to add a new note to the list of notes
      //       in position current and increment current.
      //       Tip:    key - 'a'   will be an integer between 0 and 24,
      //       inclusive, corresponding to the desired note number when
      //       the user presses 'a' through 'x'

    //    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
---->//     song.add( current, new Note( ? ));
    //      current++;
        System.out.println(key - 'a');

    }
```

I need to find a way to pass an int to a constructor that requires a Scanner. Please note that this in not the entire code but merely the code I thought would be required.

Answer (score 0):

use `int` in `Note constructor` like this

`public Note( int num )
{
    freq = num;
}`

then call it using `input.nextInt()` `song.add( current, new Note(input.nextInt()
) );`

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned I'm using the Scanner and a FileBrowser to read in from a text file so if I create the constructor like that it won't work. Thank you for answering so quickly though.